# Why am I seeing a crash when using most contentsGravity constants in NSView?

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-animation

I have an NSView subclass and in the initWithFrame method am setting the following:

```
self.wantsLayer = YES;
self.layer.contents = [NSImage imageNamed:@"sprite-sheet"];
self.layer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityLeft;
```

and when I run it, I get the expected visual results... and a crash with the following log:

> **** Misuse of NSImage and CALayer. contentsGravity is left. It should be one of resize, resizeAspect, or resizeAspectFill.

Why? There's no indication in the docs that the other values should not be used.

Comment: This is not an answer to the crash but you shouldn't set the layers contents if if belongs to a view. From the docs: "If the layer object is tied to a view object, you should avoid setting the contents of this property directly. The interplay between views and layers usually results in the view replacing the contents of this property during a subsequent update."

Comment: I understand why Apple say that but in this instance I'm exclusively using the view to animate a sprite so there's no conflict.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, the behavior you are seeing is in the documentation. It's just in the NSImage documentation and not the CALayer documentation (emphasis by me):

> ### Using Images with CALayer Objects
>
> Although you can assign an NSImage object directly to the `contents` property of a CALayer object, doing so may not always yield the best results. Instead of using your image object, you can use the `layerContentsForContentsScale:` method to obtain an object that you can use for your layer’s contents. That method creates an image that is suited for use as the contents of a layer and that is supports all of the layer’s gravity modes. **By contrast, the NSImage class supports only the `kCAGravityResize`, `kCAGravityResizeAspect`, and `kCAGravityResizeAspectFill` modes**.

Comment: OMG, never would have found that fast in the docs. Everything else nonchalantly indicates you can use NSImage as the  contents, but doesn't go into any caveats.